# Jquery slidein left-right multiple elements then out again and loop

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, transition

I am trying to achieve a certain type of animation but am certain I have it all wrong.

I'll start with what I am trying to achieve:

I have 3 H2 tag elements (as a stack), first H2 slides in from left to right with fadein at start, then the second H2 completes the same sequence followed by the third, once all three elements are animated in, they then individually slide out to the right and fadeout and then the whole sequence loops back to the start.

I have roughly tried this with the following but I am certain there is a better way of doing this... This is a true newbies attempt.

```
<body>
    <div class="fade-right-1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="photo-text">
                 <span>All rights to NASA</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fade-right-2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="photo-text">
                <span>All rights to NASA</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fade-right-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="photo-text">
                <span>All rights to NASA</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function animateDivers() {
        $(".fade-right-1").animate({
            left: 200,
            opacity: "show"
        }, 1500);
        $(".fade-right-2").delay(1000).animate({
            left: 200,
            opacity: "show"
        }, 1500);
        $(".fade-right-3").delay(2000).animate({
            left: 200,
            opacity: "show"
        }, 1500);

        $(".fade-right-1,.fade-right-2,.fade-right-3").delay(2000).animate({
            left: 500,
            opacity: "hide"
        }, 1500, animateDivers, 2500);
    }

    animateDivers();
});
</script>
```

Any help or advice on plugins out there for this would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick comment on the css you are using. `left` needs to be specified what measuring units you use like `left: 500px`. I am pretty sure you're not supposed to use `opacity: 'hide'`. FInally read up on the animate function; http://api.jquery.com/animate/  It also tells you how to trigger a new function after completion of an animation in there ;). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code, the div in the dom are already visible so animate won't work at first time. The div should be hidden initially.

Use this css:

```
.fade-right-1, .fade-right-2, .fade-right-3{
  display:none
}
```

And js as below:

```
    function animateDivers() {
        $(".fade-right-1").animate({
            left: "200px",
            opacity: "show",
        }, 1500);
       $(".fade-right-2").delay(1000).animate({
            left: 200,
            opacity: "show"
        }, 1500);
        $(".fade-right-3").delay(2000).animate({
            left: 200,
            opacity: "show"
        }, 1500);

        $(".fade-right-1").delay(3000).animate({
            left: "200px",
            opacity: "hide",
        }, 1500);
       $(".fade-right-2").delay(4000).animate({
            left: 200,
            opacity: "hide"
        }, 1500);
        $(".fade-right-3").delay(5000).animate({
            left: 200,
            opacity: "hide"
        }, 1500);
    }
   animateDivers();
   setInterval(animateDivers, 14000);
```

You need to figure out the slide in and slide out logic.